# Prestashop SSL no padlock showing

Tags: ssl, https, prestashop

I recently installed **https/ssl** on our website, however, padlock sign missing because of this!

I used why no padlock to investigate, and here you go the results.

I know where the picture is but I just don't know where to change it to https.

(I changed one url successfully from http to https but not the pictures", I really need the padlock. 
Below the results are the code of the website(where the error happens), if needed.

Total number of items: 130

Number of insecure items: 2
http=1

```
Insecure URL:1//example.com/theme...search-icon.png
Found in: 1s://example.com/index.php

Insecure URL:1://example.com/img/p/'+%20data.id_product%20+'-small_default.jpg
Found in: 1s://example.com/index.php
```

Comment: forum do not let me to post more than 2 links, so basically 1 means http

Comment: And here is the place of the code   // <![CDATA[
$(document).ready( function() {
            
$("#search_query_top")
.autocomplete(
'https://example.com/index.php?controller=search', {

minChars: 3,
max:10,
width: 500,
selectFirst: false,
scroll: false,
dataType: "json",
formatItem: function(data, i, max, value, term) {
return '<img src="https://example.com/img/p'+ data.id_product +'-small_default.jpg" /><span>' + value+'</span>';
} ,

Comment: check jquery all jquery is loading in https or not, also make sure that all the pages are loaded, also ajax calls using secure.

Comment: The theme your using could be using product images without the https even when https is enabled. If you know what files are linked without https, you can search the theme for how they are shown.